# Printing on Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, printing

I am trying to print a report where we have several different components within the xaml.
By what I`ve found, when printing, you have to treat every UIelement as a single one, thus if the desiredSize is bigger than the AvailableSize you have to activate the flag HasMorePages.

But here comes the problem.

My user can write as much text as he/she wants on the grid, therefore, depending on the amount, the row expands and goes off the printable area, as you can see on the picture below.

[image: Report]

I thought about giving a whole page to the grid, but it was to big still, which got me into a loop where the DesizedSize was always bigger than the PrintableArea.

My code is not very different from any source you find on internet when searching for Multiple Page printing.

It is based on this http://eswarbandaru.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/print-mulitple-pages-using-silverlight.html , but using Stackpanels instead of Textboxes.

Any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to work out how many pages are needed

  Dim pagesNeeded As Integer = Math.Ceiling(gridHeight / pageHeight) 'gets number of pages needed
- Then once the first page has been sent to the printer, you need to move that data out of view and bring the new data into view ready to print. I do this by converting the whole dataset into an image/UI element, i can then adjust Y value accordingly to bring the next set of required data on screen.

  transformGroup.Children.Add(New TranslateTransform() With {.Y = -(pageIndex * `pageHeight)})`
- Then once the number of needed pages is reached, tell the printer to stop

  ```
      If pagesLeft <= 0 Then
          e.HasMorePages = False
          Exit Sub
      Else
          e.HasMorePages = True
      End If
  ```

Or if this is too much work, you can simply just scale all the notes to fit onto screen. Again probably by converting to UI element.

Check out this link for converting to a UI element.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/248553/Silverlight-converting-to-image-and-printing-an-UI

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I managed  to solve a couple of days ago.